# How to use value returned by javascript in onsubmit of HTML form, in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, forms

This is my HTML form.

There is a Javascript code define in the head tag. Assuming that the Javascript code is valid.

The Javascript function returns some modified form of password.

```
<l1>
   <b>Add:</b>
   <form action="{% url 'Student:append' %}"  onsubmit="return DoPlayfair(add_password.value,ABC.value,Key1.value,'E',DupLet.value)" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="ABC" size="42" value="ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" readonly hidden>
      <input type="text" name="DupLet" size="2" value="J"readonly hidden>
      <input type="text" name="Key1" size="33"rreadonly hidden>
      <label for="add_n">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="add_name" id="add_n" value="">
      <label for="add_p">Password:</label>
      <input type="PASSWORD" name="add_password" id="add_p" value="">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="add">
   </form>
</l1>
```

---

This is my Django code.

```
def add(request):
    get_name = request.POST["add_name"]
    get_password = request.POST["add_password"]
    print(type(get_name),type(get_password))
    s = Student(student_name=get_name,student_password=get_password)
    context = { "astudent":s }
    s.save()
    return render(request,"sms_2/add.html",context)
```

I want to use that javascript changed password in this Django view. How to access it?

Comment: Looks like you have to use AJAX, do you mind posting your Javascript code?

Comment: Create a hidden input field in your form and populate that with the modified password using JS. Then you can access that input's value in django using it's name, like any other field.